# Canvas item event_generate

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'll try to run my command `nothing()` in the nested class of `item` even when the user clicks just nearby the item, but it turned to a infinite loop.

So the idea that I had was to move the mouse to the item, click the item and go back to starting position. To safe some lines I shrunk it to the problem with this bit of code here:

```
item = canvas.find_closest(canvas.canvasx(event.x),
                           canvas.canvasy(event.y))[0]

canvas.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=x, y=y)
canvas.event_generate('<Button-1>',
                      x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                      y=root.winfo_pointery())
canvas.after(20,canvas.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                      x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                                      y=root.winfo_pointery()))
```

I want to keep the structure as the following, with a subclass of tk.Frame, grid my canvas on and define the item which is done with this bit of code here:

```
class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        # DownFrame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='add', command=self.add)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body)
        self.Display.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
        
        self.body.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.Display.grid(column=0, row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')

    class item(object):
        def __init__(self,canvas, x1, y1,x2, y2):
            rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            canvas.tag_bind(rec,'<Button-1>',self.nothing)
        
        def nothing(self, event):
            print('nothing')
```

The rest of the code is garbage and just to have something to show.
An executable example can be found here:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        # DownFrame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='add', command=self.add)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body)
        self.Display.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)
        
        self.body.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.Display.grid(column=0, row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')

        self.x = tk.IntVar()
        self.x2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.y = tk.IntVar()
        self.y2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.x.set(10)
        self.x2.set(50)
        self.y.set(10)
        self.y2.set(10)
        
    def click(self, event):
        canvas = event.widget
        item = canvas.find_closest(canvas.canvasx(event.x),
                                   canvas.canvasy(event.y))[0]
        
        self.coord = (canvas.coords(item))
        x = self.coord[0]
        y = self.coord[1]
        print(item)
        print(self.coord)
        
        
        canvas.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=x, y=y)
        canvas.event_generate('<Button-1>',
                              x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                              y=root.winfo_pointery())
        canvas.after(20,canvas.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                              x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                                              y=root.winfo_pointery()))
    
        
    def add(self):
        x = self.item(self.Display,self.x.get(),self.y.get(),self.x2.get(),self.y2.get())
        
        self.old_x = self.x.get()
        self.old_x2 = self.x2.get()
        self.old_y = self.y.get()
        self.old_y2 = self.y2.get()
        self.x.set(self.old_x+40)
        self.x2.set(self.old_x2+40)
        self.y.set(self.old_y+40)
        self.y2.set(self.old_y2+80)

    
    class item(object):
        def __init__(self,canvas, x1, y1,x2, y2):
            rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            canvas.tag_bind(rec,'<Button-1>',self.nothing)
            
        def nothing(self, event):
            print('nothing')


figure = my_figure(root)
figure.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

You may have done something in the past and want share experience or you have a better idea than this, everything like this will be welcome.

You may are interested in my references that this could be done:

https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/event+generate

http://mars.cs.utu.fi/BioInfer/files/doc/private/Tkinter.Canvas-class.html

https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.event_generate-method

http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/event.htm#M9

Comment: This seems overly complicated. Why do you think you need to generate an event? Why not have the code that uses `find_closest` directly call `nothing`?

Comment: While nothing in this exampel dosent do much, in my original code it refers to some code inside the item class. At least I dont know how to handel it.

Comment: Maybe I could add the tag self to the item and then call it this way? But there are some other tags, isn't it arbitrary how the tags are coming out by gettags() ?

Comment: _"isn't it arbitrary how the tags are coming out by gettags() "_ - I don't think it's arbitrary.

Comment: I'll try to work this out and let you know.

Comment: Are you going to  have multiple types of items? If not, just move `nothing` into the `my_figure` class.

Comment: Yes, each item will create a own function by the data that it will gather. So I would need to store a bunch of date, wich I'll try to avoid. Just for your information, the tag wasnt work because the tag is a string.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Yes, all item tags are strings.

Comment: How to invoke a function by a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you need to call a method on an instance of `item` that is related to a rectangle on a canvas, and you need to be able to do that solely based on the rectangle id. You will need to create a way of translating a rectangle id to an instance of the `item` class.

The simplest solution is to:

1. save the instance of `item` in a dictionary where the key is the rectangle id
2. provide an interface for getting the instance of `item` base on the rectangle id.

Saving each instance is pretty simple: create a class variable that is a dictionary, and add the instance to the dictionary in the `__init__`. Here is a simple example:

```
class Item(object):
    _instances = {}
    def __init__(self,canvas, x1, y1,x2, y2):
        self.item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        self._instances[self.item_id] = self
```

With that, it is trivial to write a class method that can return the instance of `Item` for any canvas item id:

```
    @classmethod
    def get_item(cls, item_id):
        return cls._instances.get(item_id, None)
```

Here is a complete working example that will change the background of the closest element when you click on it by calling a method on the instance. I've tweaked `item` slightly to remember the canvas, and I'm using [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming guidelines.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=200, bg="bisque")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

class Item(object):
    _instances = {}
    def __init__(self,canvas, x1, y1,x2, y2):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.item_id = canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        self._instances[self.item_id] = self

    @classmethod
    def get_item(cls, item_id):
        return cls._instances.get(item_id, None)

    def nothing(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.item_id, fill="red")

for i in range(20):
    x1 = random.randint(0, 175)
    y1 = random.randint(0, 175)
    x2 = x1 + random.randint(10,20)
    y2 = y1 + random.randint(10,20)
    Item(canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2)

def click_closest(event):
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)

    item_id = canvas.find_closest(x, y)[0]
    item = Item.get_item(item_id)
    item.nothing()

canvas.bind("<1>", click_closest)
root.mainloop()
```

---

This isn't necessarily the best or most efficient way to solve the problem, but it gives a general idea of how to associate python objects with canvas items.

Comment: First of all thank you for your effort. I also thought about this way before, but I was afraid to build something like this, because of the real world problems I could have. So before I can accept this answer I would need to know if it's common behaivour of having 200 to 300k keys stored or will it make my code slow? As you may know Im relativly new to codeing and dont have this sort of knowlege.

Comment: @atlas435: If you're going to have 200k or 300k items on the canvas, that's a much bigger problem than the amount of memory used in a dictionary. The canvas will likely start to see performance issues at an order of magnitude less.

Comment: Then I need to get a limit on this too. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
canvas.event_generate('<Button-1>',
                              x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                              y=root.winfo_pointery())
```

When generate a `<Button-1>` event,the `<Button-1>` would also call the `click` the function again.Then it would call it infinitely.

An easy solution is check a custom state variable(maybe you need to do some revision):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()


class my_figure(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        # DownFrame
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='add', command=self.add)
        self.button.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.body = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken')
        self.Display = tk.Canvas(self.body)
        self.Display.bind("<Button-1>", self.click)

        self.body.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nswe')
        self.Display.grid(column=0, row=0,
                          sticky='nswe')

        self.x = tk.IntVar()
        self.x2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.y = tk.IntVar()
        self.y2 = tk.IntVar()
        self.x.set(10)
        self.x2.set(50)
        self.y.set(10)
        self.y2.set(10)
        
        # add here
        self.check = True

    def click(self, event):
        canvas = event.widget
        item = canvas.find_closest(canvas.canvasx(event.x),
                                   canvas.canvasy(event.y))[0]

        self.coord = (canvas.coords(item))
        x = self.coord[0]
        y = self.coord[1]
        print(item)
        print(self.coord)

        canvas.event_generate('<Motion>', warp=True, x=x, y=y)
        if self.check:
            # when call it twice, pass it.
            self.check = False
            self.check = canvas.event_generate('<Button-1>',
                                  x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                                  y=root.winfo_pointery())
        canvas.after(20, canvas.event_generate('<ButtonRelease-1>',
                                               x=root.winfo_pointerx(),
                                               y=root.winfo_pointery()))
        # restore.
        self.check = True

    def add(self):
        x = self.item(self.Display, self.x.get(), self.y.get(), self.x2.get(), self.y2.get())

        self.old_x = self.x.get()
        self.old_x2 = self.x2.get()
        self.old_y = self.y.get()
        self.old_y2 = self.y2.get()
        self.x.set(self.old_x + 40)
        self.x2.set(self.old_x2 + 40)
        self.y.set(self.old_y + 40)
        self.y2.set(self.old_y2 + 80)

    class item(object):
        def __init__(self, canvas, x1, y1, x2, y2):
            rec = canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            canvas.tag_bind(rec, '<Button-1>', self.nothing)

        def nothing(self, event):
            print('nothing')


figure = my_figure(root)
figure.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It solves part of the problem but it doesnt simulate the click, cause it dosent print nothing. :/

Comment: @Atlas435 It print the position on my device.

Comment: Yes but it dosen invoke the nothing method of the item class.